# Unable to launch application on android emulator

Tags: android, cordova

I have recently started learning to develop android apps using PhoneGap. So I set up the environment and the project as mentioned [here](http://chrisbitting.com/2014/01/06/installing-starting-with-phonegap-on-windows-for-cross-platform-mobile-development/)

The project builds fine but when I try to run it on emulator it says 'Unfortunately, HelloWorld has stopped working'

I have tried creating several projects but I get same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you created a virtual Device using the AVD? At least one virtual device needs to be created so that the emulator use it for running the android app.

Comment: Yes I have an AVD. Its working with Genymotion, thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your code is messed up or the emulator. Try to use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) which is the fastest Android Emulator. If this doesn't help then post your code.

Comment: I didn't add any code myself so it must have something to do with emulator. 
Installed Genymotion and after some initial issues, its now working. Thanks! :)